# R is the dog’s letter

Tags: alphabet, nicknames

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R):

> The letter R is sometimes referred to as the *littera canina* (canine letter). This phrase has Latin origins: the Latin R was trilled to sound like a growling dog. A good example of a trilling R is the Spanish word for dog, *perro*.
>
> In William Shakespeare’s *Romeo and Juliet*, such a reference is made by Juliet’s nurse in Act 2, scene 4, when she calls the letter R “the dog’s name.” The reference is also found in Ben Jonson’s *English Grammar*.

Do you know other letters in the English alphabet that have a nickname besides ICAO phonetic/spelling alphabet?

Comment: Would printers jargon ("mutton" and "nuts" for M and N, along with some others like "bang" for !) count, or be too close in origin to ICAO and similar (there's been a variety of ICAO-like schemes) for your interests?

Comment: @JonHanna Interesting but do not count. *Mutton* & *Nuts* are just first-letter codes.

Comment: I've saw a tutorial about [the Latin alphabet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oWWOJW3948) (the dog letter R is at 2:29). But I can't ever make that sound :p

Comment: A famous instance in which a character insults another character by equating him with a letter of the alphabet occurs in _King Lear_, Act II, Scene 2, where Kent says to Oswald (a feckless retainer of the hot Duke of Gloucester): "Thou whoreson zed! thou unnecessary letter!" But I don't think that referring to z as "the whoreson letter" ever caught on.

Answer (score 1):

Other than *R*, I could only find such a name for the letter *A*.

Graphemica lists (see under Tags)
[A, a](http://graphemica.com/A): *ox head* (may not apply to the minuscule [small letter/ lowercase] '*a*', according to some.)
[R, r](http://graphemica.com/R): *littera canina, canine letter, the dog's name*

Wikipedia refers to *ox head* in the Origins of *A*: "… the origin of aleph may have been a pictogram of an ox head in proto-Sinaitic script influenced by Egyptian hieroglyphs, styled as a triangular head with two horns extended." in the [page for the letter A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#Origins).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget "hockey stick" for the letter L!

Comment: Is this used in any context besides the euphemism "H-E-double hockey sticks?"

Comment: @Nate: There's the famous _[hockey-stick graph](http://www.pop.org/pri/sites/www.pop.org/files/images/stories/wb/hockey_stick_graph.jpg),_ which could have just as easily been called an _L-shaped curve_.